# Stream analytics small rules on high amount of device data

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

We  have the following situation.

- We have multiple devices sending data to an event hub (Interval is
  one second)
- We have a lot of small stream analytics rules for alarm
  checks. The rules are applied to a small subset of the devices.

Example:

- 10000 Devices sending data every second.
- Rules for roughly 10 devices.

Our problem:
Each stream analytics query processes all of the input data, although the job has to process only a small subset of the data. Each query filters on device id and filters out the most amount of data. Thus we need a huge number of streaming units which lead to high stream analytics cost.

Our first idea was to create an event hub for each query. However, here we have the problem that each event hub has at least one throughput unit, which leads also to high costs.

What is the best solution in our case?

Comment: Is the same subset of devices being processed by the various ASA jobs? What do the rules look like? Depending on those answers you may want to look at WebJobs/Azure Functions or an Azure ML/Javscript function instead of straight up ASA queries.

Comment: Yes, The same subset of devices is processed by multiple ASA jobs. The rules are different and cannot be joined.

Azure Functions would be a good alternative but if I use Azure Functions I have to implement self-made windowing concept.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use IoT hub and to create a different Endpoint with a specific Route for the devices you want to monitor. 
Have a look to this blog post to see if this will work for your particular scenario:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-hub-message-routing-enhances-device-telemetry-and-optimizes-iot-infrastructure-resources/
Then in Azure Stream Analytics, you can use this specific Endpoint as input.
Thanks,
JS (Azure Stream Analytics team)

Comment: The problem is that the maximum additional routing rules is 10.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not possible. IoT hub supports only 100 routing rules. See: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling